# Ubuntu on iMac (2019 - 18,3) Crashes on Suspend

Tags: suspend, mac

It looks like (sadly) almost no one uses newer iMacs for Ubuntu or Linux generally.  But I'm posting this question anyway, just in case someone out there is.

**The problem is that on any Suspend other than the first of the session after startup, the iMac **reboots** rather than suspends.**

I post below `journalctl` entries for three successive attempts to suspend: (1) after initial boot; (2) after resume from initial boot suspend; (3) after reboot from crash due to #2.  Please let me know if anything else will help!

Here they are:

**INITIAL BOOT THEN SUSPEND**

```
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038576.4448] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038576.4448] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038576.4451] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2647: instance '0x5618fbbb2000' has no handler with id '110525'
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-north".
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-east".
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-south".
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-west".
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-left-screen".
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-right-screen".
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-cycle".
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1
Apr 04 16:16:16 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1
Apr 04 16:16:19 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Apr 04 16:16:19 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Apr 04 16:16:19 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[4642]: Suspending system...
Apr 04 16:16:19 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.943 seconds
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 35: no longer affine to CPU1
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 60: no longer affine to CPU1
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 62: no longer affine to CPU1
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 33: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 56: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 64: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 54: no longer affine to CPU3
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 63: no longer affine to CPU3
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 65: no longer affine to CPU3
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: intel_pstate: Disabling energy efficiency optimization
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: CPU1 is up
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: CPU2 is up
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: CPU3 is up
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: nvme nvme0: 1/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: failed to send driver ready to ICM
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: suspend exit
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[4642]: System resumed.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1257]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <warn>  [1586038833.6925] sup-iface[0x5563887bf8f0,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1257]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038833.6937] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1257]: Successfully demoted thread 1657 of process 1639.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1257]: Successfully demoted thread 1656 of process 1639.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1257]: Successfully demoted thread 1639 of process 1639.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1257]: Demoted 3 threads.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 wpa_supplicant[984]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=82:16:f9:63:3f:18 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 wpa_supplicant[984]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 wpa_supplicant[984]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "APP", prod id 44561
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x0.0  533.25  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsync (133.3 kHz eP)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x0.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync (88.8 kHz e)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1653]: (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "3200x1800"x0.0  373.25  3200 3248 3280 3360  1800 1803 1808 1852 +hsync -vsync (111.1 kHz e)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038833.8241] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[4642]: /dev/sda:
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[4642]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[4642]:  APM_level        = 254
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-logind[969]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038833.9782] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Apr 04 16:20:33 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038833.9784] device (enp4s0f0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

**AFTER INITIAL SUSPEND, TRY AGAIN**

```
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038981.5840] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038981.5842] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[983]: <info>  [1586038981.5851] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2647: instance '0x5618fbbb2000' has no handler with id '155647'
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-north".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-east".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-south".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-west".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-left-screen".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-right-screen".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-cycle".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-north".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-east".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-south".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-west".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-left-screen".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-right-screen".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: Window manager warning: Trying to remove non-existent keybinding "move-focus-cycle".
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1
Apr 04 16:23:01 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1912]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1

Apr 04 16:23:05 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Apr 04 16:23:05 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
-- Reboot --
Apr 04 16:37:09 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Linux version 5.3.0-45-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-008) (gcc version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2)) #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 26 20:41:27 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.3.0-45.37-generic 5.3.18)
```

**ANOTHER SUSPEND (SUCCESSFUL) AFTER FORCED REBOOT FROM PRIOR SUSPEND ATTEMPT**

```
Apr 04 16:42:00 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[1014]: <info>  [1586040120.1551] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Apr 04 16:42:00 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[1014]: <info>  [1586040120.1552] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 04 16:42:00 Ubuntu-iMac2019 NetworkManager[1014]: <info>  [1586040120.1554] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Apr 04 16:42:00 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1880]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1
Apr 04 16:42:00 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1880]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js 135]: Too many arguments to method Clutter.Actor.destroy: expected 0, got 1
Apr 04 16:42:00 Ubuntu-iMac2019 gnome-shell[1880]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2647: instance '0x5629baf1c030' has no handler with id '12369'
Apr 04 16:42:02 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Apr 04 16:42:02 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Apr 04 16:42:02 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[3608]: Suspending system...
Apr 04 16:42:02 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.462 seconds
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 35: no longer affine to CPU1
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 36: no longer affine to CPU1
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 62: no longer affine to CPU1
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 33: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 56: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 64: no longer affine to CPU2
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 38: no longer affine to CPU3
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 60: no longer affine to CPU3
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: IRQ 63: no longer affine to CPU3
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: intel_pstate: Disabling energy efficiency optimization
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: CPU1 is up
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: CPU2 is up
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: CPU3 is up
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400000000).
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: nvme nvme0: 1/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: thunderbolt 0000:07:00.0: failed to send driver ready to ICM
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 kernel: PM: suspend exit
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1227]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[3608]: System resumed.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1227]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1227]: Successfully demoted thread 1641 of process 1605.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1227]: Successfully demoted thread 1638 of process 1605.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1227]: Successfully demoted thread 1605 of process 1605.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 rtkit-daemon[1227]: Demoted 3 threads.
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=82:16:f9:63:3f:18 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 wpa_supplicant[1015]: dbus: wpa_dbus_property_changed: no property SessionLength in object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 wpa_supplicant[1015]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1615]: (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "APP", prod id 44561
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Apr 04 16:57:45 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[3608]: /dev/sda:
Apr 04 16:57:45 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[3608]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Apr 04 16:57:45 Ubuntu-iMac2019 systemd-sleep[3608]:  APM_level        = 254
Apr 04 16:57:44 Ubuntu-iMac2019 dbus-daemon[1013]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.345' (uid=1000 pid=1880 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
```

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: ```DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.10"
VERSION_ID="19.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=eoan
UBUNTU_CODENAME=eoan```
```inxi``` CPU: Quad Core Intel Core i5-7500 (-MCP-) speed/min/max: 800/800/3800 MHz Kernel: 5.3.0-45-generic x86_64 Up: 16h 34m 
Mem: 1821.4/7859.5 MiB (23.2%) Storage: 957.59 GiB (1.1% used) Procs: 263 Shell: bash 5.0.3 inxi: 3.0.36

Comment: I disabled all GNOME extensions and tried again.  Here is the latest error message from `journalctl`.....```Apr 05 12:45:40 gsd-power[1135]: Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the error message pasted below still appears in `journalctl`, adding this to the boot parameter fixes the crash issue, so I am marking this solved:
`acpi_osi=!Darwin`

This appears to be a power management issue with Thunderbolt on the iMac.  There is a little bit about it [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/acpi/osi.txt).  And [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110624/what-do-the-kernel-parameters-acpi-osi-linux-and-acpi-backlight-vendor-do) is really helpful regarding `acpi` generally.

I use rEFInd (thanks Rod!), but I expect it would work with GRUB2 also.

`Error setting property 'PowerSaveMode' on interface org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed suspend problem

Edit the file （ /etc/default/grub ）and add parameters

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=!Darwin acpi_backlight=video quiet splash"`

then

`update-grub`

then

`reboot`